# TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable while using VisionTransformerModel0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-processing, tensor, vision-transformer

While trying to use VisionTransformerModel0 after splitting the datasets, I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 3
      1 from VisionTransformer import ViT
----> 3 Model = ViT((128, 128, 3), num_classes=2, num_transformer_blocks=4,
      4          embed_dim=32, num_heads=8, ff_dim=32)

File c:VisionTransformer.py:29, in ViT(input_shape, num_classes, num_transformer_blocks, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)
     26 x = layers.Reshape((-1, x.shape[-1]))(x)
     28 for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
---> 29     output = transformer_block(x, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)(x)
     31 return models.Model(inputs,output)

TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable
```

Here is my code for your reference

`from VisionTransformer import ViT

Model = ViT(input_shape=(128, 128, 3), num_classes=2, num_transformer_blocks=4,
embed_dim=32, num_heads=8, ff_dim=32)`

I need to resolve this issue and classify the datasets with this model.

Comment: It would be helpful to point out how `VisionTransformer` is implemented, or where to find its implementation.